# PHP adding Line breaks to the end of a textarea line on submit?

Tags: php, break

I'm trying to figure out how to add line breaks to the end of a textarea line when submitting a form using php. Currently i have using the nl2br() method to insert a break tag whenever there is a new line (when the user presses enter). But i'm stumped as to how I would insert at the end of every line. The nl2br() method doesn't seem to work when the user enters more then the textbox width and it jumps to a new line.

This small example shows how I want it to insert a break tag..

```
| = end of text area line

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text| <---- Insert break tag here.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text|
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text|
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text|
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text|
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: What you're asking for is generally referred to as 'word wrap'.

Comment: Thanks, I found the wordwrap() method which seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out about the wordwrap() method.